# Does the scriptures or eminent hindu acharyas, give any reasons as to why didn't Kunti invite the Trimurtis for begetting sons via Niyoga?

Tags: mahabharata, pandu, kunti

Since *Kuntī* got a boon from the legendary, *Ṛṣi Durvāsa* himself, I guess, noone would disrespect his boon thus would have descended down to beget *Kuntī* a son, as per her choice.

So, why did *Panḍu* and *Kuntī* limit themselves with the elemental or solar or netherworld deities only (i.e., *Sūryadeva*, Dharmarāj, Vāyudeva, Indradeva, & the Aśvinī Kumāras)?  Why not invite the 'higher' primordial Gods who are definitely 'more powerful' and thus more 'eligible'?
Why not call the *Trimurtis (Brahmā, Viṣṇu, Śiva)* or *Gaṇeśa*, *Kārtikeya*, etc.?

**Does any scriptures or any eminent *acharyas* or hindu personalities or saints, specify or discuss any such reasons for this presumably "hypothetical - situation"?**

Comment: The boon was about devatās, it was like "you are blessed, you will have all deva putr(son on hindi)" lord Shiva and vishnu and bhrama are not devatās they are parmatam or parmashver(Supreme God). This can be the reason

Comment: @Dark Knight - Suryadeva is extolled many times as a direct Brahman. He is also one of the *Pacha-Mahadevtas* in the *Smarta* tradition and thus, is on par, in equivalence to the other 4 deities (Ganesha, Shiva, Vishnu & the Deví). So, I think, there Must be a better and more convincing reason rather than this 'devtaa vs bhagwan' वाला reason. :P :)

Comment: Here one relationship of kunti need to be understand she is daughter-in-law of vedvyas(lord sriman Narayana) The mantra she got it from durvasa whom is regarded as father. Brahma by default will not materialize even if summoned because he will not play any role in the world he had created.

Comment: @Vivikta yes you are correct :-).

Comment: @PrasannaR maybe. what about  Shiva?

Comment: Durvasa is shiva

Comment: FYI: [Can we post mythologically hypothetical questions?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/446)

Comment: @sv. Maybe need to define what's hypothetical or not then.

Comment: @sv this is not hypothetical question when tirumurti is there why did she begot from devathas>? that is superb valid question. when you have one wish which will give moksha why would anybody aspire for oppulance or place or richness for  that matter..

Comment: @sv. I don't think this is a hypothetical question, because the questioner asked "why didn't...." and not "what if....."

Comment: It's borderline hypothetical. OP is asking why pray only to one particular god when any other god can grant the same boon. One could change Kunti to any other devotee/invoker/tapasvi and ask several questions of this type. @DarkKnight

Comment: Before asking a question on any SE site, it's probably best to ask oneself, what kind of answer will objectively address the question. So what kind of answer are you expecting here? To me this looks like an open-ended question which can lead to speculative/opinion-based answers.

Comment: Please answer my simple question: So what kind of (objective) answer are you expecting to your question? A simple reproduction of a Mahabharata passage on why Kunti prayed only to certain gods but not others?

Comment: That's because the mntra was meant for only small gods only and useless upon bigger gods like shiva Vishnu etc.
That was a vashikaran mantra and you cannot get lord Vishnu or shiva under your wish

Comment: @vivikta sir can you please post the exact boon maharshi durvasa gave to kunti.